# How to remove extra space created by echo

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to input passwords and store them in a file to later be used by an automated python program I created.

I am using a batch file specifically for this. Here is the code:

```
echo Enter new email address to be stored: 
set /p email=

echo Enter in password for the email address:
set /p password=

echo %email% >> email_list.txt
echo %password >> pass_list.txt
```

The problem I am getting with this is it will input whatever I write into the new file, except it will have an extra space after it.

For example:

I want "Password123"    instead I am getting    "Password123 ".

I have tried quoting the variable, but instead it just outputs the data in quotes (still with the extra space).

A simple issue I am sure but can someone please help me? This is proving to cause issues when my program inputs the password. Because of the extra space, the passwords are deemed 'incorrect'.

Comment: honest, practical consideration: you've got Python in your tech stack already, so replace your batch file with python, just as well. Also, upon reading your file, it would be trivial for python to strip the space, so I'd consider this whole thing a non-issue...

Comment: I know it would be easier for python. I just wanted this segment in batch for a specific reason, which turns out to be a right bummer! :(

Comment: well, as said, if this needs to be in Batch/cmd, why not simply ignore the trailing space when reading the file in python? this really should be trivial.

Comment: Because this seems like such a minor and simple issue which I couldn't explain at all and it really bugs me. I use batch frequently for other things, so I would like to understand what the issue is rather than just flat out ignoring it.

Comment: Please don't answer in your question: instead, "roll back" to your question without the solution, and post the solution as answer below - it's encouraged that you post answers to your own questions!

Comment: Ok thank you. Sorry this is my first ever question on here lol.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the space is coming from the command `echo %email% >> file.txt`

More specifically "echo %email% "

So the solution was `echo %email%>> file.txt`

Comment: great! Now I can upvote your answer! After a bit of time has passed, you can "accept" your own answer by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Comment: The correct way to do it is either, `(Echo(%variable%) 1>> OutputFileOrDevice`, or `1>> OutputFileOrDevice Echo(%variable%`, where it's best practice to double-quote an OutputFile, e.g. `(Echo(%email%) 1>> "email_list.txt"`; `1>> "pass_list.txt" Echo(%password%`. Also there's no need whatsover to use both pairs, `echo Enter new email address to be stored:` with `set /p email=` and `echo Enter in password for the email address:`, with `set /p password=`. You can instead use `Set /P "email=Enter new email address to be stored: "` and `Set /P "password=Enter in password for the email address: "`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else stumbling on this, one easy thing to do is rather than

```
echo This is error text. 2>&1
```

use

```
(echo This is error text.) 2>&1
```